# Rounded tab layout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

[image]

How can i get rounded tab layout like this in image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `TabLayout` add attribute  `app:tabBackground="@drawable/capsule_sape"`
its look like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/capsule_sape"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

For **capsule_shape** try code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
 <corners
  android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
  <stroke
  android:width="10dp"
  android:color="@android:color/transparent"></stroke>
  <solid android:color="#FFAADD" />
</shape>
```